# WebException: Single out TimeoutExceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading

I have multithreaded operation which performs a series of tasks. The problem i'm facing is a webservice that might return an [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx) when under heavy stress.

When under heavy stress (Timeout), I want the function to retry

```
Try
{
   // Do some actions here
} 
catch(WebException ex)
{
   if (// Timeout)
   { //Retry }
   else
   { // return error }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{ //return error }
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) An [Webexception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx) can occur in the following situations:

- Abort was previously called.
- The time-out period for the request expired.
- An error occurred while processing the request.

**Question:**
In my exceptionhandling, how can seperate these 3 causes and single out the `TimeoutExceptions` without using the message?

**Note:** I know i could just increase the `timeout` to resolve the issue. But that doesn't statify my curiosity.

Thank you for your time

Comment: To single out TimeoutException, you do a catch (TimeoutException ex) {...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect [Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx) property comparing to one of the [web request status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx) codes:

```
try {

}
catch(WebException ex) {
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout) {
        // Retry logic
    }
    else {
        // return error
    }
}
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25014282/1207195) for an example of retry logic. Please note that `Timeout` isn't the only reason that should trigger a retry (IMO also `ConnectionFailure` and `ConnectionClosed`, at least).

Comment: Sweet piece of code you've posted there. Should come in handy. thnx for helping me out. Must have missed the field ´Status´

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx) property of the Exception, which will contain the correct [reason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx) for the exception.

Since you are using some time-related behaviors, if you use some tests in your code I would recommend taking a look at the [Reactive extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx); it lets you configure event chains that can allow you to easily tests desired behaviors. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487965/creating-generated-sequence-of-events-as-a-cold-sequence) for an example where I wanted some events to repeat are a higher frequency in case of an error, which may interest you.

Comment: Funny enough your post deals somewhat with the same goal we're trying to achieve. Interresting read! Will look into the possibilties `Reactive Extensions`